Let $K$ be a field. If $f = \text{irr}(c_1;K) = \text{irr}(c_2;K) (c_1 \neq c_2)$ and $\deg(f)$ is odd, then $c_1 + c_2 \not\in K$
I dealt with a linear algebra question:

$f \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ is irreducible, $\deg(f)$ is odd, and $f(c_1) = f(c_2) = 0$ for $c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb{C}$. Prove $c_1 +c_2 \not\in \mathbb{Q}$

For this question, my method is here:

Denote $c = c_1 +c_2$. Then $f(c-x)$ has two common roots with $f(x)$. Since $f$ is irreducible and $\deg(f)$ is odd, then $f(x)|f(c-x)$ with $f(c-x)=-f(x)$. Thus, $f(\frac{c}{2}) = 0$ which contradicts to $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

My problem is, could we generalize this idea to arbitrary field extension $K \subseteq K[x]/(f)= K'$? (I think I can mimic this proof to any characteristic $0$ field, because we could define $\frac{c_1+c_2}{2}$, and $f(x) = -f(x)$ implies it's $0$. But this method failed for characteristic $p$ field)
If yes, could we prove it by any method using Galois group? (My first attempt is to show $c_1+c_2 \in K$ implies $\mathbb{Z}_2 < \text{Gal}(K'/K)$ which leads to a contradiction. But I don't know if it works or not) Thank you.

Well, it's false in characteristic $2$ since, for any root $c_1\in \bar K$, we have $c_1+c_1=0\in K$.

@lulu I mean $c_1 \neq c_2$, would this also fail when $\text{Char}(K) = 2$? Is there any fancy way to prove the characteristic $0$ case?

You should add that condition to your post.  It only matters in characteristic $2$...in any other characteristic, knowing that $2c\in K$ would imply $c\in K$.

Hint: In characteristic two you would get $f(x+c)=f(x)$ instead of $f(c-x)=-f(x)$. Assuming that $\deg f=2m+1$ what do you get by comparing terms of degree $2m$?

I found my idea is correct if $f$ is separable.
Suppose $c = c_1 + c_2 \in K$, $K(c_1) = K(c_2)$. And we directly have an automorphism $\varphi$ on $K(c_1)$ which is uniquely determined by $\varphi: c_1 \mapsto c_2=c-c_1$. In this case, $\varphi(c_2) = \varphi(c-c_1) = \varphi(c)-\varphi(c_1) = c-c_2 = c_1$. Thus, by the uniqueness, $\varphi^2 = \text{Id}$ which means $\mathbb{Z}_2 \approx \langle \varphi \rangle \leqslant \text{Gal}[K(c_1)/K]$.
Since $f$ is separable and irreducible, $|\text{Gal}[K(c_1)/K]| = [K(c_1):K] = \deg(f)$ which is odd. This leads to $|\mathbb{Z}_2| \nmid \text{Gal}[K(c_1)/K]$ which violates the Lagrange theorem.
In particular, if $K$ is characteristic $0$, just like $\mathbb{Q}$ in the previous question, $f \in K[x]$ is always separable which means the conclusion always holds.
